# How do I stop iOS 4 from draining the battery of my 2nd gen iPod Touch overnight?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, battery

Every since "upgrading" my 2nd generation iPod Touch to iOS 4, it seems to lose power overnight (when not plugged in). What can I do to fix this? I have tried a restore and that did not work. Seen as a problem in releases iOS 4.0.1, 4.0.2 and 4.1

Comment: any progress on the overnight battery draining? I have the same issue

Comment: Look at the accepted answer, MDB. Under iOS 4.0 and newer, the iPod touch WiFi is left running when the device sleeps. This is nice, in a way: You can get push notifications and emails without having the device active. But when you're not using it for a long period, you really *have to* turn on airplane mode. For this reason, I have the Settings app in my dock, so it shows on every home screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you don't need any network activity, I would recommend enabling Airplane Mode overnight.
2. Failing that, disable bluetooth and/or wifi if they are unnecessary
3. Disable as much Spotlight search as you can afford to by going to Settings->General->Home Button->Spotlight Search.

Comment: I think I tracked my problem down to network activity. At work I connect via WiFi to a guest network that blocks the standard email port (80) among other things. I think that the system network is getting hung automatically checking in the background. The solution that works for me is to make sure to check my email on the device when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until Apple releases iOS 4.1 that should improve overall performances on *old* iDevices, like iPod Touch 2G and iPhone 3G.

Comment: When's that going to happen?

Comment: *Soon*, as Apple released the beta 3 on August 3rd, I would say in less than one month.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check any applications running in the "multi-task" mode.  I had a issue with my iPhone 4 dieing quickly when I had certain apps still trying to queue the network.  Good luck!

Comment: There's no multitasking on a 2nd generation iTouch, I don't think. Unless it's jailbroken.

Comment: My 16g does not, but I read somewhere that the 32g would.  I'll have to look around to find the article again.

Comment: I tracked down a 32g 2nd gen iTouch with the newest iOS.  You are correct, it does not have multitasking capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone 4 and went through this issue with Apple Genius Bar guys and Level 2 support over the phone. The conclusion was the when a contact is modified on the iPhone/iPod in an Exchange account (like Gmail) the device gets into and endless loop trying to update the remote database. It stops only when finally the device is connected to a data plan or wifi connection to the server to be updated.

Strangely enough the issue is only with contacts, not with calendar or mails. It was discovered with 4.0 and it is still valid for 4.3.3.